# How to move a mail message to a folder with php imap

Tags: php, imap

I can't seem to move my mail messages to my saved folder. Here is my code:

```
$mbox = imap_open("{".$mail_server.":".$mail_port."}".$mail_folder,            
$mail_username, $mail_password) or die("Error opening mailbox: ".imap_last_error());

$countnum = imap_num_msg($mbox);
$msglist = array();

if( $countnum > 0 ) {
$num = 1;


while ($num <= $countnum) {

$msglist[] = $num;
$num++;

     }//end while loop

}

//move the email to our saved folder
imap_mail_move($mbox,implode(',',$msglist),'INBOX/Saved');
imap_expunge($mbox);
imap_close($mbox);
```

When I run this script nothing happens. The message stays in the inbox. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From looking at the docs for [imap-mail-move()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-move.php) I see you've glued your range together with `,` and your counting up from 1 so theres no need for the for loop:

```
<?php 
$mbox = imap_open("{".$mail_server.":".$mail_port."}INBOX", $mail_username, $mail_password) or die("Error opening mailbox: ".imap_last_error());

$countnum = imap_num_msg($mbox);

if($countnum > 0) {
    //move the email to our saved folder
    $imapresult=imap_mail_move($mbox,'1:'.$countnum,'INBOX/Saved');
    if($imapresult==false){die(imap_last_error());}
    imap_close($mbox,CL_EXPUNGE);
}
?>
```

Comment: check the edit `if($imapresult==false){die(imap_last_error());}
` need some errors to work with

Comment: It says invalid mailbox name, I am not sure what it should be, In squirrel mail I just created a folder called 'Saved'

Comment: Ah ha, changed it to INBOX.Saved and it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Im not sure, experiment if you can, without using INBOX or using INBOX.Saved sorry cant be much help as what I know about thos functions ive just readup to try answer :s

Comment: Change `INBOX/Saved` to `INBOX.Saved` and use 3 `===` when comparing boolean variables. Just to keep the answer 100% correct, for other people to use. I would appreciate it ^.^

Comment: @ahmadalbayati INBOX.Saved doesnt make it correct since it depends on the delimiter used in that particular mailbox, so in the end it all depends on the mailserver configuration, though most mail servers uses . as a delimiter for mailboxes folders